# Resident Evil Film Series

Tags: resident-evil, resident-evil-extinction, resident-evil-the-final-chapter

I am really a die hard fan of Resident Evil film series. I watched all series recently to get exact know-how of the plot of series and it seemed to be in a progressive and fluent way.. But there are some things which confuses me;

1. Albert Wesker is shown as Umbrella Employee as said by Alicia Markus in Final chapter, but in Extinction, he is new Chairman of Umbrella Corp.?
2. Dr. Alexander Roland Issacs is the co-owner of Umbrella alongwith James Markus and was safely upgrading underground for all these years alongwith other Umbrella committee, so Dr. Issacs that is in Extinction or previous films was a clone because in those parts, he was answerable to Wesker but in Final part, Wesker says he is loyal to Issacs?
3. Last question is of T-virus, it seems a good answer what I found here in other question that Ashford made it and Markus as head of Umbrella might have took it from Ashford to make his daughter healthy again because I agree that Alice also said in Final Chapter that he discovered T-virus not created it. But is this right? If yes, then from where it can be verified because film series and game series are a bit different by plots??
   Please reply to these 3 questions.

Comment: Please reword to to ask one question. Use multiple posts for multiple questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Chairman of a board in a company as large as Umbrella, need not be
   the owner of the same. Sometimes, they are nominal positions wherein
   people are appointed and could be either an Executive chairman,
   Non-executive chairman or even a CEO. But in movies, until the final
   movie, it wasn't clear what exactly his position per se is. But in
   the end, we see that Isaacs & Marcus are joint owners, who after
   Marcus was murdered, delegated the day-to-day running of Umbrella to
   Wesker. So, Markus and Isaacs, must have shares under their control
   which allowed the appointment of board + its chairman.
2. Yeah, all the Isaacs before the final movie were the clones, and as
   evidenced in last chapter he lacked this knowledge about him being a
   clone. Instead, all the ones before acted as Umbrella employees in
   various functions making them subservient to Wesker.
3. This bit about the T-virus is probably retconned, and the films +
   novels create the inconsistency as to who invented it. It could be
   that Markus discovered the progenitor cell (which was used as a cure
   initially) and probably Ashford then weaponized it. But again,
   T-virus history is indeed unclear.

Comment: ok thanks alot. It really means alot.. You solved one of my great misunderstandings. Now I've developed more love for this series.